# Telerik: Formatting a GridNumericColumn to not show a comma

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-ajax

I have a year column in a RadGrid.  When I edit the column inline, it's showing a comma.  Can the GridNumericColumn be formatted to not show a comma?  If so, how is this done please?

I've tried changing the datatype to various things, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  I'd like to keep this out of the code behind if at all possible.

[image]

```
            <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="YearFrom" HeaderText="Year From" SortExpression="YearFrom" UniqueName="YearFrom" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" MaxLength="4" MaxValue="9999" MinValue="0" DataType="System.Decimal">
            </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `DataFormatString` and use the following code.

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn 
    DataField="YearFrom" 
    HeaderText="Year From" 
    SortExpression="YearFrom" 
    UniqueName="YearFrom" 
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    MaxLength="4" MaxValue="9999" 
    MinValue="0" 
    DataType="System.Decimal"
    DataFormatString="{0:0}">
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks @novice_dev!  I tried that and various other data format string configurations and it didn't work.  I checked with Telerik and received an answer that I would need to use the following outside of the radgrid, while also inputing a ColumnEditorId on the radnumber columns.    <telerik:GridNumericColumnEditor ID="gridNumYear" runat="server">
    <NumericTextBox runat="server">
        <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
    </NumericTextBox>
</telerik:GridNumericColumnEditor>, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Dataformat string for Radgrid telerik]

Dataformat string for Radgrid telerik